# RSpec any_instance return self

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to stub any instance of some class. I need to stub the `fetch` method, which fills the self with some data.

How can I get access to `self` variable, modify it and return on `fetch` method?

```
MyObject.any_instance.stub(:fetch) { self }
```

doesn't return a `MyObject` instance.

Maybe, mocks is more useful in this situation. Unfortunately, I haven't understood they yet.

Answer (score 16):

There's an [open rspec-mocks issue](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/175) to address this.  I hope to get around to addressing it at some point, but it's not simple to add this in a way that doesn't break existing spec suites that use `any_instance` with a block implementation, because we would start yielding an additional argument (e.g. the object instance).

Overall, `any_instance` can come in handy in some situations, but it's a bit of a smell, and you'll generally have fewer issues if you can find a way to mock or stub individual instances.

Here's a work around that I have not tested but should work:

```
orig_new = MyObject.method(:new)
MyObject.stub(:new) do |*args, &block|
  orig_new.call(*args, &block).tap do |instance|
    instance.stub(:fetch) { instance }
  end
end
```

Essentially, we're simulating `any_instance` here by hooking into `MyObject.new` so that we can stub `fetch` on each new instance that is instantiated.

All that said, it's important to "listen to your tests", and, when something is hard to test, consider what that says about your design, rather than immediately using power tools like `any_instance`.  Your original question doesn't give enough context for me to speculate anything about your design, but it's definitely where I would start when faced with a need to do this.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see it, this doesn't seem to be possible, for some reason. I checked the current `rspec-mocks` implementation, and the method actually invoking the stub implementation seems to be the following:

```
# lib/rspec/mocks/message_expectation.rb:450
def call_implementation(*args, &block)
    @implementation.arity == 0 ? @implementation.call(&block) : @implementation.call(*args, &block)
end
```

As it seems, the block is simply invoked by itself and not through `instance_eval`. Maybe there is another technique to achieve what you want though, after all I am not an RSpec expert by any means.